# Create particle effect in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to create a particle effect in the background of my react-native app.

I am looking for something like this: http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

I can't seem to find a package that does the job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...You linked to a package that does exactly what you want.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That package doesn't work in react-native since it needs the document

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this?  I am looking into doing something similar.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up creating my own library [react-native-particles](https://github.com/nanndoj/react-native-particles)

The trick for getting a good performance was to pre-calculate the particle path and then use the `Animated` API with `useNativeDriver:true`.

Comment: is there a way to create new particles, while the previous ones are still being emmited ? Because currently in your lib, you need to wait for the current particles to be deleted before emitting new ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use react-native webview as Background